# Having additional application claims authenticating a asp.net core with Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I have an ASP.NET core v7.0 that authenticates to Azure B2C and I'd like to add further application claims in the authenticated principal but so far I was not successful.

My app is basically the WebAppMVC Azure b2C boiperplate version 7.0 :

My dependencies are:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.16.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

IN the `Program.cs` I do:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

and my conf looks like

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://myb2c.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "myClientId",
    "Domain": "myb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi_reset_v2",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_edit_profile"
  },
```

In the signup flow I have added some extra user attributes:

[image: User Attributes]

And some application claims:

[image: Application claims]

My auth works successfully, but in the authenticated principal I don't get the additional application claims that I would have expected:

[image]

So what do I need to do to have the extra application claims after successful authentication?

Comment: What are the claims you are looking for (what are missing)?

Comment: The application claims, such as the objectId